# Vb.Net - Copy files based on pattern

Tags: vb.net

I have got table named FILELISTS

```
Table Name - Filelists
Field - FileNames
```

### Data Value

1. File1.txt
2. File2.csv
3. File3*.csv

I'm struggling to write the code, as per above if it has a file name (like file1.txt and file2.txt) it needs to copy from source to destination. If file name is pattern (like File3*.csv) then copy all files that matches this pattern from source to destination.

I'm enumerating through above row in Vb.net using data reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) and [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9706cfs5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example:

```
var filePatterns = database.GetFileNamePattern(); // your method that returns the list of files
// assuming you've stored the source- and dest.-directories in the app-settings
string sourceFolder = Properties.Settings.Default.SourceFolder;      
string destFolder = Properties.Settings.Default.DestinationFolder;
foreach (string pattern in filePatterns)
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
        sourceFolder,
        pattern,
        SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(destFolder, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Sorry, here the VB.NET version:

```
' your method that returns the list of files:
Dim filePatterns = database.GetFileNamePattern()  
' assuming you've stored the source- and dest.-directories in the app-settings
Dim sourceFolder As String = My.Settings.SourceFolder
Dim destFolder As String = My.Settings.DestinationFolder
For Each pattern As String In filePatterns
    Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceFolder, pattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    For Each file As String In files
       IO.File.Copy(file, IO.Path.Combine(destFolder, IO.Path.GetFileName(file)), True)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: As im new to vb.net, so basis question - as per the above example if filename = file1.xls then it will download file1.xls, and it its pattern it down all pattern files. Mean pattern can be a filename or filepattern

Comment: @ConradJagger: What means "download"? I have assumed that the file is already somewhere on the server.

Comment: Apologies download mean COPY. Only query, if we give FILENAME to PATTERNS field, will it work or PATTERN only accepts wild card type (for e.g. *.csv)

Comment: @ConradJagger: I'm not sure if i understand your last comment. The pattern of `Directory.EnumerateFiles` works with or without the wildcard `*`. Have a look at the provided msdn link for further informations.

Comment: This only works with Version 4 and above and I'm using old version 2.0.5. Please help

Comment: @ConradJagger: Then replace `Directory.EnumerateFiles` with [**`Directory.GetFiles`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

DirectoryInfo, FileInfo - - You deleted your other question before I could click post... but this works with .net framework 2.0, like you asked

```
Option Strict On
Imports sO = System.IO.SearchOption
Imports dI = System.IO.DirectoryInfo
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each F In (New dI("C:\")).GetFiles("*.*", sO.TopDirectoryOnly)
            MsgBox(F.FullName)
            'Do your copy here
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```